# Calling .NET DLL in Inno Setup

Tags: .net, dll, inno-setup

I'm trying to load a DLL written in C# into Inno Setup.

Here is the code:

```pascal
function Check(version, dir: String): Integer;
external 'Check@{src}\check.dll stdcall';
```

Then I call it like `Check(x,y)`

But the DLL couldn't be loaded.

I tried it with `stdcall` and `cdecl`.

The `check.dll` file is along to `setup.exe`.

Why isn't it working?

Comment: I simply use a batch file (which fires commands in the CMD console) to register my DLLs as I would one by one: @echo off echo Registering DevExpress DLLs %~dp0gacutil.exe /i %~dp0DevExpress.BonusSkins.v12.1.dll %~dp0gacutil.exe /i %~dp0DevExpress.Charts.v12.1.Core.dll

So, I place this in the RUN section of the iss script: [Run] Filename:C:\myFolder\RegisterDevExpress.bat"

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

Use the Unmanaged Exports library to export function from a C# assembly, so that it can be called in Inno Setup.

- Implement a static method in C#
- Add the [Unmanaged Exports NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports/) to your project
- Set *Platform target* of your project to *x86*
- Add the `DllExport` attribute to your method
- If needed, define marshaling for the function arguments (particularly marshaling of string arguments has to be defined).
- Build

```
using RGiesecke.DllExport;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace MyNetDll
{
    public class MyFunctions
    {
        [DllExport(CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static bool RegexMatch(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string pattern,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string input)
        {
            return Regex.Match(input, pattern).Success;
        }
    }
}
```

On Inno Setup side (Unicode version):

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "MyNetDll.dll"; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]
function RegexMatch(Pattern: string; Input: string): Boolean;
    external 'RegexMatch@files:MyNetDll.dll stdcall';
```

And now you can use your function:

```pascal
if RegexMatch('[0-9]+', '123456789') then
begin
  Log('Matched');
end
  else
begin
  Log('Not matched');
end;
```

---

See also:

- [Returning a string from a C# DLL with Unmanaged Exports to Inno Setup script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20776847/850848)
- [Inno Setup Calling DLL with string as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53575880/850848)
- [Inno Setup - External .NET DLL with dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45955312/850848)

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Unmanaged Exports](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports) from Robert Giesecke.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. Managed DLLs do not export functions directly. Calling DLLs from InnoSetup requires the function to be directly exported.

The problem is the same when trying to use managed DLLs from C++ for example. This can not be done except when using COM, as described [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736/en-us).

You should use a native Win32 DLL.