# inno CreateOleObject unicode

Tags: inno-setup

I had a working .net dll exposed as a com object using the non unicode version of inno.  It has been working for a long time and has not had any changes.  I am trying to convert to the unicode version of inno, and ran into an issue where calling CreateOleObject now throws "The parameter is incorrect, ProgId: ***"

To recreate this issue...

Create a C# project named samplecom and mark the assembly as COM-Visible in the project properties/Assembly Information

Use the following code in the default Class1.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace samplecom
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class MyClass
    {
        [ComVisible(true)]
        public string MyMethod()
        {
            return "Hello from COM dll";
        }
    }
}
```

Build the project and then from a DOS/command prompt as Administrator register the dll using RegAsm, Note: the following assumes you are in the same directory as the dll or the samplecom\bin\debug folder

c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe samplecom.dll /tlb:samplecom.tlb /codebase

Then using the following script test using but the non unicode and unicode versions of inno

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Sample COM
AppVersion=1.0
DefaultDirName={pf}\samplecom

[Code]
Var
  comObject: Variant;

function NextButtonClick(CurPage: Integer): Boolean;
var
  hWnd: Integer;
begin
  if CurPage = wpWelcome then begin
    comObject := CreateOleObject('samplecom.MyClass');

    log(comObject.MyMethod());
  end;
  Result := True;
end;
```

Here is output of ansi version of inno

```
[15:50:23.779]   *** Setup started
[15:50:25.435]   Setup version: Inno Setup version 5.5.8 (a)
[15:50:25.437]   Original Setup EXE: C:\dev\innosandbox\Output\setup.exe
[15:50:25.439]   Setup command line: /SL5="$82622,56832,56832,C:\dev\innosandbox\Output\setup.exe" /SPAWNWND=$92602 /NOTIFYWND=$1A2580 /DEBUGWND=$5310D8 
[15:50:25.440]   Windows version: 10.0.14393  (NT platform: Yes)
[15:50:25.441]   64-bit Windows: Yes
[15:50:25.443]   Processor architecture: x64
[15:50:25.445]   User privileges: Administrative
[15:50:25.446]   64-bit install mode: No
[15:50:25.450]   Created temporary directory: C:\Users\Keith\AppData\Local\Temp\is-E13L9.tmp
[15:50:35.234]   Hello from COM dll
```

**Update: 3/9/2017**

**Here is a link to the project along with a copy of the inno script.**

https://www.dropbox.com/s/nxkwtgm086dtokv/InnoCom.zip?dl=0

I am not sure if it is related or a different issue, but using vbscript/cscript I am able to load the COM object using 32bit vbscript/cscript but it fails to load using the 64bit vbscript/cscript

The test.vbs file

```
Dim objXL
Set objXL = WScript.CreateObject("InnoCom.Inno")
```

Comment: We need [mcve].

Comment: I added example code to post

Comment: Note: The regasm must be run as administrator

Comment: Are you sure it works in the Ansi version of Inno Setup? I'm getting the same (similar) error both in Ansi and Unicode version.

Comment: it did, I saw the output of the log command, what error are you getting in the ansi version?

Comment: *"The parameter is incorrect."* in Ansi version. *"The parameter is incorrect, ProgID: "samplecom.MyClass3""* in Unicode version.

Comment: I deleted my C# project and recreated it, and added output of ansi version to post

Comment: Perhaps you are running a newer version of the ansi version?  Mine shows 5.5.8 (a) when I run Inno Setup Compiler, if not I'm not sure why you are getting same thing in both versions.

Comment: In either case, which parameter is incorrect?

Comment: I used different versions (including the latest 5.5.9) with the same result. Can you share your project, including the built DLL? - It's probably some internal parameter somewhere deep in the code that creates the OLE. The error message has probably nothing to do with your Inno Setup code specifically.

Comment: See update to post at bottom

Comment: The same. Does not work for me in either version. - Anyway, did you consider exporting the functionality using plain functions, instead of COM objects? You can use [UnmanagedExports](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports).

Comment: Actually I cannot load your DLL even into the 32bit JScript (I can load other .NET assemblies though).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42711143/850848

Comment: I was able to get unmanaged exports working, but is there a way to use an inno interface to encapsulate the external functions inside an interface?  The dllfunction1, dllfunction2, dllfunction3 just rubs me the wrong way.  I would rather be able to do object.function1, object.function2

Comment: I do not understand. You can name the function whatever you want.

Comment: Some new info on this problem.  The 32bit version 5.5.8 does not have the issue, but the 32bit version 5.5.9 does.  Same code/project.

Comment: What was the end of the story?

Answer (score 1):

Inno Setup's v6.0.3(u) help gives the answer. Under ["Pascal Scripting: Using COM Automation objects"](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptautomation), the line just above "IUnknown based COM" the text reads:

> If you're using a .NET COM object and loading it fails since Inno
>   Setup 5.5.9 try putting this line in your script before creating the
>   COM object: `LoadDLL(ExpandConstant('{sys}\mscoree.dll'), ErrorCode);`
>   and add a variable `ErrorCode` of type `Integer`.

For me it solved the issue mentioned above.

See https://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptautomation.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try **isetup-5.5.8-unicode.exe** version from official site (http://files.jrsoftware.org/is/5/). My .net dll works great with version **5.5.8** when I use *CreateOleObject* and don't work with version 5.5.9 and higher. Also see the Revision History http://www.jrsoftware.org/files/is5.5-whatsnew.htm . Maybe you will find a solution for later versions.

5.5.9 (2016-04-06)

To further help protect installers against potential [DLL preloading attacks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff919712.aspx), Setup/Uninstall now calls SetDefaultDllDirectories if available to remove the application directory from the DLL search order. If SetDefaultDllDirectories is not available or cannot be called, it now additionally preloads a set of system DLLs known to be loaded unsafely by older or unpatched versions of Windows.

**Change in default behavior:** the `OutputBaseFileName` `[Setup]` section directive now defaults to `mysetup` instead of `setup`. Setting it back to `setup` is not recommended: all executables named "setup.exe" are shimmed by Windows application compatibility to load additional DLLs, such as version.dll. These DLLs are loaded unsafely by Windows and can be hijacked. If you do so anyway, the compiler will issue a warning.

Added new `[Files]` section flags: `sign` and `signonce`. Instructs the compiler to digitally sign the original source files before storing them. Ignored if `[Setup]` section directive `SignTool` is not set. Inno Setup's own compiler files are now also signed.

`[Setup]` section directive `LZMADictionarySize` now allows the LZMA dictionary size to be increased up to 1 GB from the previous maximum of 256 MB. Review the memory requirements listed in the `Compression` topic before using!

Improved the "auto-retry" feature of the `[Files]` section: it now also retries if MoveFile failed even if the preceding DeleteFile succeeded. Additionally, if MoveFile keeps failing it will now register the file to be replaced on restart if the `restartreplace` `[Files]` section flag is used instead of displaying an error message.

The value of the `AppVersion` directive is now not only used to set the `MajorVersion` and `MinorVersion` values in the Uninstall registry key when possible but also used to set the *VersionMajor* and `VersionMinor` values as required by newer versions of the Windows App Certification Kit.

Inno Setup Preprocessor (ISPP) changes:

Added new function `RemoveFileExt`.

Documented predefined variable `ISPPCC_INVOKED`.

Console-mode compiler (ISCC) change: Added new command line parameter `/J`. Can be used to `#include` additional files.

Unicode Inno Setup: Added official Armenian translation.

Minor tweaks.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).