# Inno Setup 'Could not call proc' when using 64-bit class library

Tags: .net, dll, inno-setup, class-library

- Inno Setup version 5.6.1(u).
- Dev Studio 2015 64 bit class library.
- .NET Framework 4.6.1
- Uses the UnamanagedExports package.

Here's the script:

```pascal
[Setup]
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64
ArchitecturesAllowed=x64

[Files]
Source: "DotNet64.dll"; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]
function TestFunction(): Boolean;
external 'Testing@files:DotNet64.dll stdcall setuponly delayload'; 

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
var
  ires : Boolean;
begin
  if CurPageID = wpWelcome then begin
    ires := TestFunction();
  end;
end;
```

Here's the C# DLL code

```
using RGiesecke.DllExport;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace DotNet64
{
    public class InnSetDLL
    {
      [DllExport("Testing", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
      public static bool Testing()
      {
         return false;
      }
   }
}
```

As soon `TestFunction()` is called in the script, I get a popup:

> Runtime Error (at 2:55): Could not call proc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the DotNet64.dll compiled as a 64 bit DLL?  InnoSetup can't access 64 bit DLLs as per the [documentation](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_64bitlimitations.htm).  You can compile it as a 32 bit DLL or write a 64 bit EXE that calls your 64 bit DLL and execute the 64 bit EXE.

Comment: Indeed. Just set *Platform target* of your project to *x86* - See [Calling .NET DLL in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8487925/850848#42711143).